# Angular conversion second in timestamp

Tags: angular, typescript, date

hi I have a question concerning the conversion of a date, I have the execution time of a response which is for example 20 seconds, in Angular to be able to store it on the database I have to transform it into a timestamp the problem is that by doing so I don't understand how store the timestamp only which refers to the seconds and not to the day, month, year.

Can anyone give me a possible solution?

Answer (score 1):

How about you just store the execution time of your response in seconds as an `int` in the database and then you can convert it into seconds, minutes, hours or whatever you want when you get it from the db to display in your Angular component.

When you insert the record in the db, you must be capturing the datetime of the record inserted, so in case if you do need the date you can get it from that column.

Hope this helps.